# highchart get series color and marker

Tags: javascript, colors

I'd like to display the color and the marker of the series of a line chart next to the table where i display the data. I didnt set the the color manually.

How can i get the series color and marker via JavaScript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var clr0 = chart.series[0].color;
var mrk0 = chart.series[0].symbol;
```

Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSMU5/).

Comment: Thanks alot that was what i am looking for! i jsfiddle, var mrk0 = "circle", how can i get the image of the marker to display in a div?

Comment: You'll need to create the images yourself in each colour that's likely to be used. Then just display the appropriate image in your div.